# Submitting form doesn't return next page

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a registration process implemented across several different ASP.NET pages. The pages themselves work, but when I click submit on any of them I am presented with a message just like this

{"Successful":true,"Exception":null,"InnerException":null,"ReturnVal":3}

The `ReturnVal` I am receiving is correct. It seems like once the `AJAX` function completes, it just stops and doesn't continue to either the error or the success, it just displays the `JSON` result. Here's a snippet:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Next" id="Package" onclick="return  DoAjaxSubmit(this);"/>
    </div>
</div>
</p> 

<script type="text/javascript">

   function DoAjaxSubmit(btnClicked) {
       var form = $(btnClicked).parents('form');
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: form.attr('action'), //'<%=ResolveUrl("~/register/go") %>',
           data: form.serialize(),
           dataType: "json",
           error: function (xhr, status, error) {
           },
           success: function (response) {
                if (response != null) {
                   if (!response.Successful) {
                       alert("Please select the Package");
                       return false;
                   }
                   else {
                           switch (response.ReturnVal) {
                       case 0:
                           window.location.href = "/Register/Free";
                           break;
                       case 1:
                           window.location.href = "/Register/Confirmation";
                           break;
                       case 2:
                           window.location.href = "/Register/AdOptions";
                           break;
                       case 3:
                           window.location.href = "/Register/PrintOptions";
                           break;
                       case 4:
                           window.location.href = "/Register/JobOptions";
                           break;
                       case 5:
                           window.location.href = "/Register/Landing";
                           break;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       });
       return false;
   }
```

The controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [RestrictedAction(new[] { "user" },null)]
    public JsonResult Package(string[] package)
    {
        var t = new TransactionResult();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(package[0]))
            {
                //Reset Session values in case of start over
                Session[SessionNames.PRINTOPTIONS] = null;
                Session[SessionNames.JOBOPTIONS] = null;
                Session[SessionNames.ADOPTIONS] = null;
                Session[SessionNames.LANDING] = null;
                Session[SessionNames.QUANTITY] = null;
                Session[SessionNames.PACKAGE1] = package;

                //Determine which options page to navigate to
                t.ReturnVal = 6;
                foreach (var p in package)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(p) < t.ReturnVal && Convert.ToInt32(p) != 1)     t.ReturnVal = Convert.ToInt32(p);
                }
                if (t.ReturnVal == 6) t.ReturnVal = 1;

                t.Successful = true;  
            }
        return Json(t);
    }
```

I've tried removing the return value on the submit button, adding return false;, setting the Successful attribute for the `JSON` result to be false in the `controller` to check to see if the error portion works, but it just does the same thing (except it returns false, but the error message doesn't display).

EDIT Console errors

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined Package:283
    DoAjaxSubmit Package:283
    onclick Package:263
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json:   "http://192.168.0.21:82/register/package".
```

Comment: Can you see some javascript errors in the console?

Comment: It seems you haven't registered jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the error message you are getting it seems that you haven't registered the jQuery script. Make sure that you have registered jQuery before using it:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also if you are using another client side javascript framework which is using the `$` function you could [`configure jQuery with noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Answer (score 0):

One thing wrong:

```
switch (response.returnValue)
```

should be:

```
switch (response.ReturnVal)
```

You have to use the same property names in the JS that are in your JSON.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I changed it but I'm still presented with the same problem.